# D3js stack chart X-axis customization

Tags: json, d3.js, graph

I followed this example [d3js example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768).
then customized this graph as given in this [image: Image]![changes: Now stack is only 2 colours]

My JSON data is:

```
{"test": [
            {"date":"1/5/2014","allocated":"14.14","unallocated":"7.14"},
            {"date":"1/6/2014","allocated":"10.38","unallocated":"1.14"},
            {"date":"1/7/2014","allocated":"1.43","unallocated":"3.14"},
            {"date":"1/8/2014","allocated":"12","unallocated":"6.14"},
            {"date":"1/9/2014","allocated":"13.34","unallocated":"4.44"},
            {"date":"1/10/2014","allocated":"6.34","unallocated":"1.14"},
            {"date":"1/11/2014","allocated":"8.34","unallocated":"2.14"},
            {"date":"1/12/2014","allocated":"6.88","unallocated":"4.14"},
            {"date":"1/13/2014","allocated":"23.34","unallocated":"2.14"},
            {"date":"1/14/2014","allocated":"3.34","unallocated":"0.14"}
]}
```

and Index.html code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bar Graph</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.29.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?1.29.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.time.js?1.29.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.csv.js?1.29.1"></script>

svg {
  width: 550px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var w = 550,
    h = 500,
    p = [20, 30, 30, 20],
    x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w - p[1] - p[3]]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h - p[0] - p[2]]),
    z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["lightpink", "lightblue"]),

    parse = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse,
    format = d3.time.format("%a");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + p[3] + "," + (h - p[2]) + ")");
var t

d3.json("test.json", function(test) {
  // Transpose the data into layers by cause.
  var causes = d3.layout.stack()(["allocated", "unallocated"].map(function(cause) {

    return test.test.map(function(d) {
      // var temp = _.each(test, function(record){
        date = parse(d.date);
        array = [date]
        // console.log(array)

        var week = d3.time.format("%U");

        var nest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return week(new Date(array)); })
            .entries(array);
        // console.log(nest)
        disp = [nest]
        console.log(nest)


      return {x: array[0], y: +d[cause]};
    });
  }));

  // Compute the x-domain (by date) and y-domain (by top).
  x.domain(causes[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(causes[causes.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  // Add a group for each cause.
  var cause = svg.selectAll("g.cause")
      .data(causes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "cause")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(z(i)).darker(); });

  // Add a rect for each date.
  var rect = cause.selectAll("rect")
      .data(Object)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

  // Add a label per date.
  var label = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(x.domain())
    .enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) + x.rangeBand() / 2; })
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(format);

  // Add y-axis rules.
  var rule = svg.selectAll("g.rule")
      .data(y.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "rule")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + -y(d) + ")"; });

  rule.append("svg:line")
      .attr("x2", w - p[1] - p[3])
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d ? "#fff" : "#000"; })
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(d) { return d ? .7 : null; });

  rule.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", w - p[1] - p[3] + 6)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(d3.format(",d"));
});

    </script>
    <tr>
      <!-- <td>Previous</td> -->
      <td>Next</td>
    </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now on the X-axis thi code is showing all the rows in given JSON data. 
My need is i wanted to display only data of only single week at a time. Means i have numbers of rows in JSON and I managed to nesting of days into a week.

Please help me to customize X-axis with given code now. I am trying to call values of Nested array on X axis, but it is not giving proper output.
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want the X-Axis to look like?

Comment: It should display only columns of **Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat** (week 1) data. and then On NEXT click it should display (week 2) data.  Refer above image

Comment: Ah ok.  I think you will have to (1) make a button that says "next" then (2) add to that button an .on("mouseclick" …) event.  That event will probably be to call some kind of redraw() function that contains an enter - update - exit transition. I am still learning that myself and there are a lot of tutorials.  This one helped me a lot: http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For That you need to do groupBy to your **JSON** data.

You can try this simple method to implement:

```
var groupedByWeek = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
        var dateMoment = moment(item.day,"DD/MM/YYYY");
        return dateMoment.week();
```

It will convert days into a week!